# Angular not working but not posting any errors to the console

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a pretty basic Angular app.

When I try to run it in the browser, the page is blank. But no errors show up in the Chrome console.

Could this have been turned off somehow?

---

**UPDATE**

I found the problem to be that I gave `angular.module(...)` a variable name, but forgot to update the chained calls with the variable. So it looked like this.

```
var app = angular.module(....);

.config(..);
```

However, I'm still wondering why I didn't see that error in Chrome

Comment: Have you loaded the app with the ng-app attribute?

Comment: @DanielIgnat Yes I did. See update